# Copy a picture to a Excel Application Object

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I want to copy a picture from a worksheet named "ws_d" to a newly created excel application object named "ExcelSheet", I wrote the code as follow but the picture didn't paste to the new workbook:

```
ws_d.Shapes(1).Copy

ws_d.Paste Destination:=ExcelSheet.Application.Range("B1")
```

Could anyone kindly correct my code so that the picture could be pasted. Many thanks.

Comment: You're using the wrong sheet for the paste - use something like `excelsheet.application.activesheet.paste...`

Comment: Can we see the whole code please?  `Range` can't be accessed like that directly from the application.  Application > Workbook > Worksheet > Range.   Maybe `ExcelSheet.Range("B1")` all depends what ExcelSheet is.

Comment: Sorry buddies. I found that using ```ws_d.Cells.Copy ExcelSheet.Application.Cells``` can copy the picture from old worksheet to the new workbook. But then I have encountered another issue, I got a cell with data validation in old worksheet, but then it cannot be propagated to the new workbook. May I have your kind help on this? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "excel application object"? An Excel session, a workbook or a sheet? Supposing that it is a workbook, it does not have a `Range` property. You need to paste in a sheet. And what you show in your recent comment shouldn't work, I'm afraid. How Excel to know in which sheet to paste the cells you try copying?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Actually, ranges *can* be accessed like that (it's the default for an unqualified range reference in a normal module).

Comment: @Rory  Never knew that.  My lesson for the day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub testCopyShape()
 Dim ws_d As Worksheet, ExcelSheet As Workbook
 
   'set the above objects as you need__________________________
   '...
   Set ws_d = ActiveSheet 'use here what you need
   Set ExcelSheet = Workbooks("workbook name") 'use here its REAL NAME
   '___________________________________________________________
   
   ws_d.Shapes(1).Copy

   ExcelSheet.Worksheets(1).Paste 'to paste in the workbook first sheet
   'move the shape where you need:
   With ExcelSheet.Worksheets(1).Shapes(ExcelSheet.Worksheets(1).Shapes.Count)
        .Left = ExcelSheet.Worksheets(1).Range("B3").Left
        .Top = ExcelSheet.Worksheets(1).Range("B3").Top
    End With
End Sub
```

This way does not need selecting/activating anything. Otherwise, you could activate the necessary sheet (`Worksheets(1)`), select the range where to paste and then use `Worksheets().Paste`, to place the shape on the before selected cell.